# Transform characters; like A to B, B to C,

Tags: php, regex, string, character

I want to have a short and easy way to replace character:
A to B, B to C, Z to A, ... in PHP.

I already have tried this:

```
$pwd = "Abc";
for($char = ord('A'); $char <= ord('Z'); $char++) {
  $newc = $char+1;
  if($newc > 90)
    $newc = 65;
  $pwd = str_replace(chr($char), chr($newc), $pwd);
  $pwd = str_replace(chr($char+32), chr($newc+32), $pwd);
}
echo $pwd;
```

But when I use it I only get "Aaa"...

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please show us your work/attempts which you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I added it to the main post. :)

Comment: @LuucDev So where are we now with this question ?

Comment: It is still a *here's a code dump fix it for me* question, it is close to being closed again. Read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, if you really want help you will kep trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'a';
echo ++$str; // prints 'b'
```

Comment: For every character of course. And I don't really want to type in this line for every character... ^^

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Here I simply [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) the string into an array and then go through each character with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). There I check if it is either a lowercase or an uppercase letter.

If yes I simply return the character incremented and if it goes over `zZ` I just return `aA`.

At the end I simply [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array again into a string.

```
<?php

    $str = "Aac";

    $str = implode("", array_map(function($v){
        if(ord($v) >= 65 && ord($v) <= 90)
            return (++$v > 90 ? char(65) : $v);
        elseif(ord($v) >= 97 && ord($v) <= 122)
            return (++$v > 122 ? char(97) : $v);
        else
            return $v;
    }, str_split($str)));

    echo $str;

?>
```

output:

```
Bbd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple loop that does the job:

```
// A function to replace uppercase characters in a string with
// the next letter in the alphabet

function replace($str) {
    $len = strlen($str);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        // Check if the current character is an uppercase letter

        if (ctype_upper($str[$i])) {
            if ($str[$i] == 'Z') {
                // If it is a "Z", simply make it an "A"

                $str[$i] = 'A';
            }
            else {
                // If it is anything else, just get the next
                // character from the ASCII table

                $str[$i] = chr(ord($str[$i]) + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
echo replace('HELLO, YOU! ABCDEFGH...XYZ');
```

This will output `IFMMP, ZPV! BCDEFGHI...YZA` as expected.

You can read more about `ctype_upper` here: http://php.net/ctype-upper - it is basically a function to check whether a string or a character is uppercase or not.

`chr` and `ord` just convert an ASCII code to a character and vice-versa. Read the official documentation if necessary: http://php.net/ord and http://php.net/chr.